# SonarQube - how is version determined?

Tags: sonarqube

SonarQube has a "since previous version" filter. How does Sonar determine version number? I have a Maven project with version numbers in a pom file - is Sonar smart enough to interrogate this?

Comment: you can even check sonarqube version in the logs generated on the mvn sonar:sonar command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the property `sonar.projectVersion` that control the version number of your project.

But indeed if your are using the SonarQube Maven plugin to do your analysis (`mvn sonar:sonar`) then this property is automatically set using version declared in your pom.xml.

Comment: in pom.xml it is specified as ```<sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.6.0.1398</sonar-maven-plugin.version>``` - see https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin, however, what is the relationship between sonar plugin version and sonarqube versions? it is said that after sonarqube 6.4 we can ignore ```common-java:DuplicatedBlocks``` error, but with the latest sonar plugin ignore does not work... -